# Finding the identity element of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to determine if $G=\mathbb{R};$ where $a\cdot b = a+b-ab$ is a group. I'm not sure how to find the identity (if it exists). My best guess is to just pick integers like 0 or 1 and see if I can find an inverse for any given element and test if it works. However, I am sure there is a more efficient way, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The neutral element $e\in\mathbb{R}$, if it exists,  satisfies $a=e\cdot a= e+a-ea$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, which is equivalent to $$0=e-ea=e(1-a)$$
for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$, so we must have $e=0$. Conversely, it is the case that $$0\cdot a=0+a-0a=a$$ and $$a\cdot 0=a+0-a0=a$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$Possibly the most efficient way is to notice that this is just the ordinary product on $\R$ in disguise. That is, consider the map $f : \R \to \R$ that sends $x$ to $1 - x$.

Consider the ordinary product $\cdot$ on $\R$, your operation (that I will call $\circ$), and the two sets with an operation $(\R, \cdot)$ and $(\R, \circ)$.

Then $f : (\R, \cdot) \to (\R, \circ)$ is an isomorphism, as
$$
f( x y) = 1 - x y = (1 - x) + (1 - y) - (1 - x) (1 - y) = f(x) \circ f(y).
$$

Look up [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure).

Also, your operation $\circ$ plays an important role in the theory of the [Jacobson radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical).